# Pushforward of pullback of a sheaf on $X\longrightarrow S$ via projections from $X\times_S X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Assume $X\longrightarrow S$ is a nice scheme, and $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf on $X$. Let $\pi_i: X\times_S X\longrightarrow X$ be the canonical projections, $i\in\{1,2\}$.

I read in a book of Berthelot and Ogus that the sheaf $(\pi_1)_*(\pi_2)^*\mathcal{F}$ is isomorphic to the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_S}\mathcal{O}_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{F}$ when $X$ is affine.

1. Why should this not hold generally when $X$ is not affine?
2. Why do we need to take pullback via one projection and pushforward via another projection? Wouldn't we get the same sheaf if we consider $(\pi_1)_*(\pi_1)^*$? What is the point of that operation?

Comment: (1) When $X$ Is affine and $S$ is affine, you can interpret these pullbacks and pushforwards as extension of scalars and restriction of scalars. In the case of $X$ not affine, this interpretation need not hold unless $X$ is quasi-coherent. So I suspect it need not hold unless you at least assume $\mathscr{F}$ is quasi-coherent and $X$ is noetherian.

Comment: (2) Think about the adjunction of $(-)_*$ and $(-)^*$ and what that implies in this case. You can try an example, but I'll write more when I get the time.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I would accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Following up on one of my comments. Suppose $X:=Spec(A)$ is affine and $S:=Spec(B)$ is affine and so $A$ is just a $B$-algebra. Then it is known e.g. Hartshorne Chapter II.5 that $f^*\mathscr{M}=\widetilde{M\otimes_B A}$ for $\mathscr{M}=\widetilde{M}$ a coherent $\mathcal{O}_S$-module. Whereeas $f_*\mathscr{N}=\widetilde{N|_B}$ for $\mathscr{N}=\widetilde{N}$ a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module (coherence isn't important here).

Onto the matter at hand. Let me answer your point 2. first.

Let $\mathscr{F}=\widetilde{M}$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$ and $M$ an $A$-module. Then the claim boils down to saying that $(M\otimes_A (A\otimes_B A))|_A$ is isomorphic to $M\otimes_A (A\otimes_B A)$ as an $A$-module. This is certainly clear I hope.

Now what if you swapped it with $\pi_{1*}\pi_1^*$? Then you'd be saying $(M\otimes_A(A\otimes_B A)|_A$ is isomorphic to $M\otimes_A  (A\otimes_B A)$. What's the difference because they look the same?

The matter is how you choose to take the restriction $|_A$ !! The restriction in the first case (1) comes from restricting via the $A$-module structure given by $A\rightarrow A\otimes_B A$ sending $a\mapsto a\otimes 1$ while the second one (2) swaps $a\mapsto 1\otimes a$.

But how was the tensor product taken? The extension of scalars was done by viewing $A\rightarrow A\otimes_B A$ as an $A$-module via $a\mapsto 1\otimes a$ in both cases. So one can check that only the first choice (1) gives the right isomorphism.

**Warning. This part of the answer is vague.** Now let me explain the issue with 1 from what I understand. If $X$ were not affine, we would at least hope for quasicoherent $\mathscr{F}$ for something like this to hold. Even then, it is not readily clear to me that affine is absolutely needed here. For pushforwards to be well-behaved w.r.t. quasioherence, we'd need hypotheses on the maps such as in Hartshorne Proposition II.5.8. But the projection map need not satisfy quasicompactness e.g. $\mathbb{A}^\infty\times\mathbb{A}^\infty\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^\infty$ is not quasicompact.